# Treat directory as a binary or as a single file in git

Tags: git, binaryfiles

I'd like to put some Omnigraffle files under version control. Omnigraffle stores those files as `.graffle` directories.

I'd like git to treat these directories as a single file.

How should I do that?

I tried putting `*.graffle binary` in `.gitattributes` but it does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: A bad solution I found: create a loop filesystem into `.graffle` and mount it, so on the git side, it "just works."

Comment: Omnigraffle saves files as packages, which are basically directories. I want to version control the Omnigraffle documents, not `.graffle` folders' content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To treat the directories and their contents as a single file you would need to write smudge/clean scripts. Any reason that you need to do this and can't keep them as is?

If they cumbersome, large and too heavy, you might want to put them in a separate repository and use **submodules** to link them.

Answer (score 8):

For OmniGraffle specifically, if you go to the Document:Document inspector, you can choose to always save the file a flat file instead of a package, which makes it easier to work with in git.